# Coluna de ChekBox no datagridview

Tags: c#, sql-server

Estou recebendo um erro depois que coloquei uma coluna de chekbox no datagridview na minha tela, sendo que esta tela e carregada por uma query, coloque esta coluna de chekbox não na query mas sim diretamente no datagridview.[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

segue o codigo

```
private void ListaGrid()
    {
        try
        {
            SqlCommand separacao = new SqlCommand("usp_SeparacaoPic", conexaoDADOADV(true));
            separacao.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            separacao.ExecuteNonQuery();

            SqlDataAdapter dados = new SqlDataAdapter(separacao);
            DataTable dtLista = new DataTable();
            dados.Fill(dtLista);

            dgw_separacaopic.DataSource = dtLista;

        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Não exstem dados digitados para a consulta, por favor verificar!!!");
            return;
        }
    }
```

Desde já agradeço.

Comment: Não tem o valor na lista que está enviando, por isso do problema ou o tipo que está enviando não é `boolean` (verdadeiro ou falso), o que está sendo enviado?

Comment: Virgilio obrigado por responder, mas na coluna não estou passando valor nenhum, somente criei a coluna no datagridview, e não configurei nada nela.

Comment: quando você faz `dgw_separacaopic.DataSource = dtLista;` aquela coluna precisa de um valor

Comment: Virgilio vc pode me explicar como dou um valor para a coluna ??

Comment: traga um valor padrão na sua StoredProcedure `usp_SeparacaoPic`

Comment: Virgilio entendi, vou fazer aqui muito obrigado.

Comment: Deu certo aqui obrigado.